# Displaying Custom Product image on Opportunity

Tags: image-formula, cross-object

I have created a formula field that displays an image if a product has gone "End Of Life"  this is based on a date field that is managed on the **Product** Object.

This is also displayed on the **Opportunity Product** both in the compact view and on the page  and related list on the Opportunity.

I want to display this image on the **Opportunity**, if even one of the Opportunity Products is displaying this EOL image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a RSF on Opportunity `Opportunity_Product_Expired_Count__c` that counts the OpportunityLineItem where the associated Product2 is end of life.

Because you can't do RSF on cross object formula fields you are faced with coercing a custom field value in OpportunityLineItem, let's call it `Is_End_of_Life__c` whenever a Product2 goes End of Life. This becomes the basis for the RSF.

Thus, you will need a trigger on `Product2` that then mass updates all child `OpportunityLineItems` to set this field to true.  This may require setting off a batch job as there could be tens of thousands of affected `OpportunityLineItem` children.